# Ruby - Parse array of json files

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, ruby-parser

I have an array of json files.this is the sample of single json file,

```
{
  "job": [
    "admin",
    "developer"
  ],
  "name": "dave"

}
```

i need to get the "name" value if admin exist in "job". Need to do the same for other json files in the array.

Helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming if `hash["job"]` is present its an Array.

```
require 'json'
str = '{ "job": [ "admin", "developer" ], "name": "dave"}'
hash = JSON::parse(str)
# => {"job"=>["admin", "developer"], "name"=>"dave"}
name = hash["name"] if hash["job"] && hash["job"].include?("admin")
# => "dave"
```

Comment: I guess you need to wrap it into loop and update str, it suppose to be the array of items...

Comment: That would be based on our assumption for OPs original data structure which is not shared with us.

Answer (score 1):

Read the json file to hash using File Handling.

1) You need to require JSON before JSON parse.

```
 require 'json'
```

If the above step returns false then probably you don't have json gem installed on your machine. Install JSON gem using the following command.

```
gem install json
```

2) Open JSON file for parsing : Create file handle to parse JSON file.

```
file = File.read('file-name-to-be-read.json')
```

The above command will open the file in the read mode.

3) Now parse the data from the file.

```
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
```

The above command will parse the data from the file using file handle created with name 'file' and variable data_hash will have parsed hash from the file.

4) Now if we take the example mentioned in the question.

```
{
  "job": [
    "admin",
    "developer"
  ],
  "name": "dave"
}

require 'json'
file = File.read('file-name-to-be-read.json')
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
```

The data_hash will contain `{"job"=>["admin", "developer"], "name"=>"dave"}`

Now the key "job" from the above hash consist of an array that includes ["admin","developer"]. You can use the following ternary command to find out the name if the job is "admin".

```
data_hash["job"].select{|x| x == 'admin'}.any? ? data_select["name"] : "not found"
```

any? checks for the job, if it is 'admin' then it will provide the name.